# HP Pavilion G6 at 12.04 LTS - boot failure. In rescue mode boots successfully

Tags: 12.04, boot, hp-pavilion

12.04 LTS AMD64 fails if boot is not in rescue mode with HP Pavilion G6.

At boot, grub presents 2 boot options:

- normal boot
- rescue mode

If I choose rescue mode, Ubuntu loads okay.

if I choose normal boot, I see only a black screen with console cursor at left-top corner of screen and nothing else, any keys work.

How I can fix problem?

If need technical details (logs/configs/hardware) please tell which exactly.

Answer (score -1):

There is a ppa for it. but be careful. This is a kernel update.

[ppa description](https://launchpad.net/~kamalmostafa/+archive/linux-kamal-mjgbacklight)

read this carefully AND FOLLOW THE DESCRIPTION AN THE PAGE.

Comment: This PPA supplies a patched Ubuntu Maverick (10.10) or Natty (11.04), NOT 12.04. Unless you have additional details for us. Have you tested it against 12.04?

Comment: I don't own a G6 or even a laptop.  I'm sorry but I'm not able to do a test. This is just the result of a quick Google search.